# How to scroll nested container without scrolling parent container in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript

I have a situation where I have one container like contentContainer and the second container mainContainer. I want to make the second container scrollable and the first container as non scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

try referencing the inside container:

```
trace( Maincontainer.insidecontainer);
```

also if its a component you set the scrollable property to false, if you dont understand me or need help let us no i will make you a sample file to explain...